# Executing program while camera capture Windows Phone 8 SDK

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, camera, windows-phone-8-sdk

I am working on a project which calls a function attached with a timer. However, when the camera capture is active, the function is not called. I suppose this happens since the camera capture task needs to complete before any other task is started. Is there any way to make the timer work even when the camera capture is working? Code snippets would be of great help.

Thank you.

Comment: Use background process

Comment: Hi Manvik, can you elaborate a little more? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `CameraCaptureTask`, the app is indeed suspended until the task has ended.

So if you need to have your app running while taking a photo, you should use the `Windows.Phone.Media.Capture` APIs. Here is a link on MSDN on [Advanced photo capture for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Olivier. I did try on these lines. I am a little stuck at these stage. I believe I need to do something to the following line:
        
        await camsequence.StartCaptureAsync();

Though I am not sure what I should do.